# Playing opus files under ubuntu

Tags: linux, ubuntu, audio, codec, command-line-tool

Opus is a new audio codec standard for audio on the web. Features include:

- Better compression than mp3/ogg/aac.
- Good for both music and spoken word.
- Dynamically adjustable bitrate, audio bandwidth, and coding delay.
- Good for real-time and pre-recorded applications.

Since 2012, all major browsers have had support for playing Opus files in HTML  and  elements directly. Ref: http://xiph.org/~giles/2012/opus/. UPDATE: check [this](https://docs.google.com/document/d/1DnD1eoDleJ3rmclV4Is9-1M-j2SE4Gl6833wkij-cvc/edit?usp=sharing) out for [more info on Opus](https://docs.google.com/document/d/1DnD1eoDleJ3rmclV4Is9-1M-j2SE4Gl6833wkij-cvc/edit?usp=sharing).

However, the question is, how to play opus files under ubuntu normally, without using the browsers? What I found are:

- [Opus players on 12.04 relies on /dev/dsp, which is obsoleted](http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=2108073)
- [Opus codec has to be custome build into audacious in order for
  audacious to work](http://redmine.audacious-media-player.org/boards/1/topics/821)

Time has passed, can opus files being played easily under ubuntu now? 
Also, how about playing from the command-line?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are still using Ubuntu 12.04, I suggest you update to the current LTS release (14.04).  The default music player included with Ubuntu 14.04 is called Rhythmbox and can play Opus files.

Comment: Rhythmbox can't play .opus files.

Comment: Any cli solution without reencoding?

Comment: I can't tell you the Ubuntu package names, but on Linux generically you have several alternatives: `play` from [SoX](http://sox.sourceforge.net/), `ffplay -nodisp` from [FFmpeg](https://ffmpeg.org/), or `audacious -Hq` with a new enough version of [Audacious](http://audacious-media-player.org/), just to name a few.